How are opamp node voltages being set in the following circuit and what is the use of the diode configuration?
I am using a PCB which has the following opamp configuration implemented. It's supposed to be a precision buffer for the source V3. I accidentally connected the source V4 as well and observed strange behaviour which is being mimicked in the following simulation as well. I am not able to understand how the opamp is able to regulate it's feedback in a configuration like this. But as you can see from the pictures below, the opamp maintains the virtual short at the inputs. Only output changes based on the value of V4. Without V4 connected it acts as proper buffer as intended. But I am not able to understand the use of diodes D1 and D2 and resistor R3.
Original configuration (V4 connected)

Effect of change in V4

Effect of change in V3 (feedback maintained nicely)

PCB designer's intended use configuration- can't understand the use of D1, D2 and R3

Update: Even removing the resistor and connecting guard to output maintains the feedback, but how??


Diodes are parts of the ESD system. See Fig 99 datasheet https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada4530-1.pdf Don't understand why they are wired to output. Read also page 30 the § "Input protection".

V4 makes no sense. It unconditionally sets the potential of the inverting input, killing any negative feedback, and causing the op-amp to behave as a comparator. You say the virtual short is maintained, but I do not see that. The inv. and inon-inv. inputs have different potentials when V4 is present, as I would expect.

@SimonFitch take a look at the images, inverting and non inverting terminals are tracking each other. The difference is only 0.000145mV, I wouldn't call that a break in feedback.

Try and make R1 smaller and then see if that changes the voltage at the inverting node. You have to remember bias currents.

Where  did you find this circuit? Please link to the source.

So the first thing that stands out is that none of these configurations are proper usage of the guard voltage circuit. The guard trace should not be electrically connected to anything. For your stated application of buffering (Output voltage = input voltage), figure 107 (p34) from the datasheet is the intended circuit. Note that Rshunt1 and Rshunt2 represent the leakage resistance of the input and output traces, not a circuit component.
My best guess is that the intent of the guard trace shielding the input and output voltage got confused somewhere along the way and it got connected instead.

Datasheet Link for Reference
By making electrical connection to the guard circuit, you find two things going on (See equivalent opamp schematic below):

there are clamping diodes implemented internally that limits the voltage difference between each input pin and the guard pin to about 0.6V, and the maximum voltage difference between the IN+ and IN- pins to 1.2V. In almost all of your configurations, these diodes are conducting as part of the primary opamp feedback path.
The output buffer for the guard pin (BUF1) is much weaker than the main output of the op-amp. A major reason for this is the added R1 in series with the output of BUF1 limiting the current. It is a precision voltage buffer designed to sink/source currents in the nanoamp range.


Looking at the first case, the feedback path for the unity gain buffer is through D2 in your schematic and the internal guard diode D4. R2 and R3 have no significant impact on loop regulation, and D1 is reverse biased. In this case, the internal D1 diode would also be forward biased and conducting, but no impact is observed because V3 is an ideal voltage source. The second case where V4 is set to 2.0V is similar, but different diodes are conducting and part of the feedback network. The schematic diode D2 will now be conducting, as well as the internal D3.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your final case is very similar. Without the external diodes, the only diodes remaining are the internal diodes on the guard pin. In this case, the internal D3 diode is forward biased to allow the output to pull down the inverting input pin to the same voltage as the the non-inverting input pin.


+1. I'd like to have post your answer, but I'm very busy in these days. There's only a  thing I'd add and it is on the practical side. I'd recommend to the Asker not to try this circuit on the real board, for if they'd do so, they'll surely degrade the input bias current performance of this wonderful amplifier.

You would never run this circuit with a voltage source at V4.  But if you do, look at the following explanation and internal op amp schematic from the data sheet:



The guard buffer amplifier supplies a guard voltage from the positive input.  You are driving the negative input of the op amp with the guard buffer amplifier through the internal diodes.  In normal operation, the guard buffer is used to provide a voltage to a guard ring and/or guard layers around the input signal, so that leakage current is minimized through the PC board material.  It is not meant to drive a resistive load.

The buffer is supposed to maintain the potential difference between INP and Guard 0 but that is not happening as you can see in the simulation. So I don't get its role here.

The guard circuit should not be connected to the output.  I can't see why anyone would do this, and I would not trust a simulation with the circuit as shown.  Instead, disconnect the guard and tie it to a ring surrounding the two input legs of the amplifier, if it is needed.  If not, leave it disconnected.
